# Is there a name for the Windows 10 kind of design?

Tags: interface-design, design-principles, style-identification

The design used in Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform apps is one used in a lot of modern interfaces. So like how there are many types of designs, from the day of Swiss and Bauhaus to this day of material and flat design -- what is this design called?

---

[image]

Some attributes to make my question more specific:

- Your prime focus is clarity.
- White is the primary color.
- Solid bars of dark colors like red, blue, or black are used on left or right of text, items, etc. to separate them.
- Colors are flat. Decent paddings are given.
- Invisible margins.
- Rectangle shapes are spammed anywhere they can be.

Comment: Personally i'd describe the style as "Terrible"

Comment: I agree, @DigitalLightcraft. I'd call it a boring trend, and I don't like it either. One main reason is, so much information is removed and you really have to hunt to find it. I like clean design, but feel that the Windows 10 is too sparse with useful information.

Comment: So there's basically no name? I think I can call it super clean design then lol

Comment: @DocPixel I agree with your complaint about the amount of information removed. That's not so much the fault of the design language though as how it is often applied. Minimalism in UI is deceptively difficult to pull off in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official name is [Microsoft design language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29). It was previously known as Metro but changed in 2012.

If I was *forced* to categorize it somehow, I'd call it "flat minimalism". Although I don't see how useful it is to really categorize something like this. I would call it "Microsoft design language". If I was writing about design, I'd specifically expand on what that means.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's called Metro, similar to Windows 8.

Comment: its the artist formerly known as metro ;)